# DVI interface current requirement

Tags: current, display

I am using DVI(display visual interface) interface supporting FHD at 60fps. What is the current requirement of DVI interface.

Comment: Did you not search for a datasheet?

Comment: It is not a matter of searching a datasheet of any specific chip, but searching the DVI specifcation which defines the interface.

Answer (score 4):

The Digital Visual Interface Specification 1.0 (freely available & not hard to find) says source must provide 55mA and sink must not consume more than 50mA when off or 10mA when active.

Comment: Can you cite a specification document or link to a pdf?  Numbers from thin air, while useful right now, will not make your answer useful in the future.

Comment: I did cite where the info comes from. The Digital Visual Interface Specification 1.0 is freely available for anyone and not hard to find so anyone can check it. I did think should I answer this question, or should I ask what prevents the OP from downloading the specs and finding the answer there. The official site for downloading the specs does not exist any more, so I decided not to put a link to any specific site for downloading, as I can't guarantee the trustworthyness of any random website.